# split non digit from decimal power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

Using power query we can split a column into data that is non digit to digit which works great when you have a value such as `Lead 10` to split into `Lead` and `10` however is there anyway to split in the same way if the number is a decimal e.g. `Lead 20.5`. Using split non digit to digit splits this is `Lead` `20.` `5`

I have the following example data I wish to split as follows:

```
Lead 20.5 --> `Lead` `20.5`
No Data --> `null`
Arsenic 10 --> `Arsenic` `10`
Gold 50.55 --> `Gold` `50.55`
1,4-Dioxane 21 --> `1,4-Dioxane` `21`
```

Previously I used split by right most "" however this splits No Data into separate words.

Any ideas on how to achieve this would be great.

**Update 1: Issue 1,4-Dioxane**
[image]

M Code:

```
    let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9","."}, c), {"0".."9","."}), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"})

in
     #"Split Column by Character Transition"
```

Comment: Have you tried left() and right() with find() using the space in find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to do this depends on your data.

**Edit**
*to account for additional data sample with digits in chemical name*

**Algorithm**

- Test the last word

  - if last word is NOT a number, then replace spaces with NBSP
  - Then split on the rightmost space.

*I will use a custom function to check the last word and modify the string if the last word is not a space*

***Custom Function* M Code:**
*enter as a blank query and rename it: **fnConvString***
*Edited to improve computation*

```
//Rename this query "fnConvString"
(string as text) =>
let 
   lastWord = Text.AfterDelimiter(string," ",{0,RelativePosition.FromEnd}),
   lastIsNumber = try Value.Type(Number.FromText(lastWord)) = type number otherwise false,
   replSpace = if lastIsNumber = false then Text.Replace(string," ",Character.FromNumber(160)) else string
in 
   replSpace
```

**Main MCode**
*Edited to simplify code with no added columns*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table29"]}[Content],
    addNBSP = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{"Column1", each fnConvString(_)}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(addNBSP, "Column1", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image]

***Edit without custom function***

*If you would prefer to not use a custom function, you can incorporate that within the main code as a `Transform Operation`:*

***M Code without custom function***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table29"]}[Content],
    
    addNBSP = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{"Column1", each 
        let 
            lastWord = Text.AfterDelimiter(_," ",{0,RelativePosition.FromEnd}),
            lastIsNumber = try Value.Type(Number.FromText(lastWord)) = type number otherwise false,
            replSpace = if lastIsNumber = false then Text.Replace(_," ",Character.FromNumber(160)) else _
        in 
            replSpace
    }),

    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(addNBSP, "Column1", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: Hi there this is fine since there shouldn't  be a lone `.`  however I have noticed that its also splitting if a material has a comma.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @nick  Please show a data example.  I cannot reproduce from what you write.

Comment: @Nick Maybe you inadvertently included a comma within the quote marks when you edited your M Code?

Comment: Please see update. I copied the code as exact and yet `1,4-dioxane 21` splits into `1,` `4-Dixoane`

Comment: @Nick The problem is not that the material has a comma; the problem is that the material has **digits**.  Let me look at that more closely.

Comment: Ah okay yes that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you! Useful answer for a general issue i'm sure others run into.

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery, based on sample data, looks like you could just split on the space character.

Right click column .. split column .. by delmiter ...  delimiter:space ... Split at: leftmost-delimiter

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"})
in  #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

If data doesn't like that method, you could parse numerical from alpha

Add custom column with formula

```
= Text.Remove([Column1],{"0".."9","."})
```

to get the text only portion, and adding a second custom column with formula

```
=try Text.Remove([Column1],Text.ToList(Text.Remove([Column1],{"0".."9","."}))) otherwise null
```

to get the numerical portion

Sample full code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Text", each Text.Remove([Column1],{"0".."9","."})),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Numeric", each try Text.Remove([Column1],Text.ToList(Text.Remove([Column1],{"0".."9","."}))) otherwise null)
in  #"Added Custom1"
```

Comment: This is good but I have issues when spliting data such as `1,4-Dioxane 21`.  It splits into ,-Dioxane and 1421.

Comment: I appreciate i didn't include this in the example data. I have added it now to improve the question.

Comment: Splitting on a space still looks like it would have worked fine